# "General user", "End user" or "Normal user", which one is better?

Tags: word-choice

On a website I am working on, people are classified into two groups: one is programmers who create programs with C# 4.0 and share with other people, the other is common users who use the programs to calculate.

I don't know how to name the "other" group: "general user", "end user" or "normal user"? Which one is better?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 5):

How about simply "User" versus "Programmer"?

It is enough to make the right distinction and you don't have to call anybody "common" or anything.

Comment: You can think about my suggestions.

Comment: As Mr. Shiny suggests, you could choose more specific names according to their roles. If there is only one "non-programmer" group, go with users. If there are more, you could consider stuff like "manager", "operator", "viewer" etc, based on their access levels or responsibilities. Other than that, I couldn't provide more suggestions without knowing the system itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are describing the system it would be perfectly correct to call this group 'end users', however, I agree with Ishmaeel in the case that you want to give the group a visible name then simply 'users' would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Paul, I work in the software industry and End User is a widely accepted terminology.
It describes the people who will actually be using your software to meet their ends.

It's fine if you want to use "User" but "End User" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: "End User" is jargon. We software professionals may call the end users, "end users", but the end users do not necessarily know that they are being referred to as "end users". So, "End User" is perfectly acceptable, but only as part of an internal terminology, not on the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's best to name the users based on the role they are performing. Programmers are users of the system too, but they are programming it. The other users are operating those programs, but "operator" sounds wrong to me.  In this case if there is no defining characteristic for the non-programmer users then simply calling them "users" is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

To build on other answers, you may want to try:

- application users
- system users
- point-of-sale users
- novice users
- expert users
- customers